# Register model from Azure Machine Learning run without downloading to local file

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

A model was trained on a remote compute using azureml.core Experiment as follows:

```
experiment = Experiment(ws, name=experiment_name)
src = ScriptRunConfig(<...>)
run = experiment.submit(src)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

How can a model trained in this run be registered with Azure Machine Learning workspace without being downloaded to a local file first?

Answer (score 4):

The model can be registered using [register_model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py#register-model-model-name--model-path-none--tags-none--properties-none--model-framework-none--model-framework-version-none--description-none--datasets-none--sample-input-dataset-none--sample-output-dataset-none--resource-configuration-none----kwargs-) method available on the run object (click the link for documentation).

Example:

```
model = best_run.register_model(model_name='sklearn-iris', model_path='outputs/model.joblib')
```

The following [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/ml-frameworks/scikit-learn/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-sklearn/train-hyperparameter-tune-deploy-with-sklearn.ipynb) can also be used as an example for setting up training experiments and registering models obtained as a result of experiment runs.